# Python pandas regex extract to 4 new columns

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'data': ['2 (B) - 15 (K)']})
print(df)
```

Current DataFrame:

```
             data
0  2 (B) - 15 (K)
```

What am looking to do is to extract `2`, `B`, `15` and `K` into 4 new columns within the same dataframe.

is that possible using pandas.regex directly?

Comment: do you always have the same format with spaces-parenthesis-dash in your data?

Comment: Yes that's correct but there's records which is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the same pattern spaces-parenthesis-dash and empty strings, this way works

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'data': ['2 (B) - 15 (K)', '']})
print(df['data'].str.extract('(\d*).\((.)\).-.(\d*).\((.)\)'))
#      0    1    2    3
# 0    2    B   15    K
# 1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract all characters that are numeric or alphabetical using `str.extractall`, then unstack the result:

```
>>> df.data.str.extractall("([A-Za-z1-9]+)").unstack()

       0
match  0  1   2  3
0      2  B  15  K
```

To re-assign the extracted values to the original dataframe, you can use:

```
df[["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]] = df.data.str.extractall("([A-Za-z1-9]+)").unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, if i applied the same within my DataFrame, i can see it if i printed the line as you did, but how to do it to print the new dataframe with changes? https://bpa.st/5BGA

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, see my updated answer for assign the columns back to your original DF

Comment: Thank you, your solution now is giving `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` while Ben solution works fine. not sure what the reason for that